# How to get string base64 in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, base64

This is my code:
but not get the string base64 in my variable.
I need the string base64 in this variable var base64.
I have seen other issues but none of them meets what I need

```
<input type:file multiple id="files">



 <script>
function listarchivos(){
    var base64; //in this variable i need the base64
    var selectedFile = document.getElementById("files").files;
           var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
     getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
                      data => alert(data)
                    );
               }

    //This is my function for get base64, but not return the string base64
    function getBase64(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
            return Promise.resolve(reader.result)
        });
    }
    </script>
```

the function that I have already complies with obtaining the base64 string of the file that is given as a parameter, what I can not do is get access to that string to assign it to a variable and use it.
I just need you to tell me how I can get access to that base64 chain, I just need it in a variable that can be handled as desired.

```
 I have already tried the following options
  var base64 = getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
                          data => alert(data)
                        ); //this not works

getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
                          data => base64 = data
                        ); //This not works

getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
                          data => return{data}
                        );//this not works
```

Comment: replace `typt:file` with `type="file"`

Comment: Did you bind a change event to the input? Cause I just tried your code and it worked.

Comment: if it works, but I want that base64 string that prints in console to assign it to a variable.
var base64 = "jahsdjhkajhljksadiquiuqweiuqweasdhjlajsdhljhadjskhewqruyuiyad" // expectation of variable with string value base64

Comment: I just need to assign the data that is being painted on the console to a new variable that can be manipulated

Comment: try to do so select a file with the input file, and try to assign the data (printed on the console) to the variabe var base64 that I have in my code and you will see that variable base64 will print you undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Promise` makes the function asynchronous, the following code would start running `getBase64()` and continuously executing `console.log(base64)` which is not defined yet.

```
function listarchivos() {
  base64; //in this variable i need the base64
  var selectedFile = document.getElementById("files").files;
  var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
  getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
    data => {
      base64 = data;
    }
  );
  console.log(base64) // undefined
}
```

So you should `await` for `getBase64()` be done or use a callback like the followings.

**await example 1**

```js
async function listarchivos() {
  var base64; //in this variable i need the base64
  var selectedFile = document.getElementById("files").files;
  var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
  await getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
    data => {
      alert(data);
      base64 = data;
    }
  );
  console.log(base64)
}

//This is my function for get base64, but not return the string base64
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    return Promise.resolve(reader.result)
  });
}

$('#files').on('change', listarchivos)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple id="files">
```

**await example 2**

```js
async function listarchivos() {
  var base64; //in this variable i need the base64
  var selectedFile = document.getElementById("files").files;
  var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
  base64 = await getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
    data => {
      return data;
    }
  );
  console.log(base64)
}

//This is my function for get base64, but not return the string base64
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    return Promise.resolve(reader.result)
  });
}

$('#files').on('change', listarchivos)

function DoSomething() {
  console.log(base64)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple id="files">
```

**callback**

```js
var base64;

function listarchivos() {
  var selectedFile = document.getElementById("files").files;
  var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
  getBase64(fileToLoad).then(
    data => {
      base64 = data;
      DoSomething()
    }
  );
}

//This is my function for get base64, but not return the string base64
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    return Promise.resolve(reader.result)
  });
}

$('#files').on('change', listarchivos)

function DoSomething() {
  console.log(base64)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple id="files">
```